# Is it possible to use PuTTY as the UI for the Windows shell?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, shell, putty

PuTTY is much better than cmd.exe. Can I use PuTTY to execute Windows commands?

Comment: If you want an alternative command line interpreter, look at TCCLE http://jpsoft.com/tccle_cmd_replacement.html - If you want something better than the gui that cmd.exe offers, look at Console 2 http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/ - I have used this combonation for a long time.

Comment: FYI: PuTTY is only a terminal. It doesn't execute commands, only forwards them to a (remotely running) shell. `cmd.exe` is a shell. It doesn't have a GUI and doesn't handle copy-pasting; that's the job of a terminal (usually the Win32 Console). If you use PuTTYcyg in place of Win32 Console windows, you'll get your copy/paste behavior, but you would *still* be running commands in `cmd.exe`.

Comment: @grawit I downloaded PuTTYcyg, but it was using the cygwin interpreter. I executed the `cmd.exe` interpreter inside it but it lost its auto-completion feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way you could achieve this is to install an SSH or Telnet server into Windows. Windows comes with a Telnet server in the *Add/Remove Windows Components*.

Then you can use PuTTY to connect to the local computer and log in.

**However**, you will *still* be running cmd.exe within PuTTY, so you won't really gain anything by this - in fact it will probably be **worse**.

If you want the full Bash experience you should look at installing [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to give you a more Linux-like interface.

Comment: What I don't like in `cmd.exe` is how to copy and paste there. Putty would make it easier.

Comment: @Jader:  Use CMD within Console2 then.  You can define any keyboard shortcuts for Copy and Paste.  I use CTRL+C and CTRL+V.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/  I hide the toolbar.

Comment: I use cygwin with puttycyg: http://code.google.com/p/puttycyg/

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can use [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat):

```
nc -L -p 1234 -e cmd.exe
```

And then connect to localhost on port 1234 using PuTTY (RAW type connection). It is still not the best, but at least you don't have to install SSH or Telnet servers. (Also, Unix-like color codes seem to work for example:

```
grep --color=always ...
```

Using [Windows grep](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) seems to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to Cygwin, you can get more minimalistic bash environment with MSys-Base.

- get [mingw-get](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/)
- install msys-base using `mingw-get install msys-base`

For terminal use [MinTTY](https://code.google.com/p/mintty/) which is very similar to PuTTY.