# Keep PuTTY inside command line

Tags: windows, command-line, ssh, putty, cmd.exe

Is it possible to run a PuTTY session within cmd.exe, without using the PuTTY console?

Kind of the opposite of this question: [Is it possible to use PuTTY as the UI for the Windows shell?](https://superuser.com/questions/270300/)

Comment: You can ssh within MobaXTerm and Cygwin without PuTTY.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is PLINK which is an add-on utility to PUTTY.

Please read the manual carefully.
You can get all sorts of unexpected behavior as the Windows console is NOT a real terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Sort of. `Putty` is a `telnet client`. The `CMD` version is called telnet.

By default it is not installed with windows, but its easily installed, by doing the following:

**Installing Telnet**

1. Open your control panel
2. Go to Programs and Features
3. At the left side, click on Turn Windows features on or off
4. Scroll down and tick `Telnet Client`
5. Press OK to install telnet.

And presto. You can now type `telnet <server> <port>` to initiate a connection. For example: `telnet mywebserver.com 80` or `telnet 192.168.1.25 22`

Comment: What about ssh?

Comment: @Alexander Good question. Telnet can only handle telnet sessions, not SSH. For SSH, the putty commandline options would work as mrkmg has posted.

Answer (score 2):

```
\Path\To\Putty\putty.exe [-ssh | -telnet | -rlogin | -raw] [user@]host
```

Retreived from http://etherealmind.com/putty-command-line/

This article will explain all the steps if you want to omit using a full path

Comment: It is still opening a putty windows, isn't it?

Comment: @Alexander is totally right. Plink is what you are going to want and there **will** be issues if you are using standard CMD.exe as many of the commands to move the pointer, paint colors, etc will just print to screen. You are best to use the Putty Console.